# Python For Loop list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm new to Python and I'm currently trying to work some lists. I have a list with objects with each object having two attributes:

```
for s in objlist:
s.attribute1
s.attribute2
```

The problem with this is that I want to read and process *two* objects at a time, like this:

```
s1.attribute1
s1.attribute2
s2.attribute1
s2.attribute2
```

And then have the loop "skip" the next object as it was already processed.

In Java it'd be something like this:

```
for [int i = 0, i<list.length, i = i+2]
list[i].attribute1
list[i].attribute2
list[i+1]attribute1
list[i+1]attribute2
```

And then just allow it to iterate with i+2 to the next *pair* of objects.

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: I believe you are looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same in Python also,

```
for i in xrange(0, len(seq), 2):
    seq[i].attribute1
    seq[i].attribute2
    seq[i+1].attribute1
    seq[i+1].attribute2
```

[`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) will give a range of numbers one at a time. It starts with `0`, ends at length of `seq` and the step value will be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your list is evenly sized:

```
for x, y in izip(objlist[::2], objlist[1::2]):
    x.attribute1
    y.attribute2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    print x[i], x[i+1]
    i += 2
```

and your x list must be an even size